# Is there any difference in versions of Chrome across Android OS versions?

Tags: android, chrome

In checking Google Analytics to get develop a browser support list for my site, I'm finding that almost all (*see below*) Android versions are using the same version of Chrome (at the time of this writing it's 51.0.2704.81).

If there are not any functionality or rendering differences between the same version of Chrome on different versions of Android, this will simplify testing greatly.

Does any one know if this is the case?

Thanks.

*The one exception I'm seeing is that LG devices using 4.4.2 seem to be stuck at Chrome version 34.0.1847.118.*

Answer (score 1):

Certainly there are differences between version but of course it depends on what specific version you compare.

As for seeing most traffic under 1 version, this may be a side-effect of most recent versions using the evergreen approach to constantly update to the latest versions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14555389/631619

My current Ubuntu Chrome version is 51.0.2704.106, very very close to your listed version.

Try running those analytics over longer time periods to see browser versions slowly rolling forward for evergreen browsers.

Answer (score 0):

A random person on StackExchange can't know whether you can safely test your site against only one version of Chrome for all Android versions.  You need to consider who your users are, what happens if the the site breaks on a different Chrome versions, and whether the downside is worth the additional testing effort.

Comment: Update my question with more specifics.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood.